# Rotating text using Textrenderer

Tags: scala, jogl, textrenderer

Hey, I'd like to display text in a 2D szenario using JOGL. But I can't figure out, how to rotate text using com.sun.opengl.util.j2d.TextRenderer. It does not have any methods concerning the rotation. So I was expecting the modelview matrix to have an effect on the rotation.

```
val renderer = new TextRenderer(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 36))

[...]

renderer.beginRendering(drawable.getWidth(), drawable.getHeight())
  gl.glRotatef(90,0,0,1)
  renderer.draw(content, 0, 0)
renderer.endRendering()
```

Do you know any help?

Answer (score 2):

For me, the following order -- and only the following order -- works:

```
renderer.beginRendering(...)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glPushMatrix()

glRotatef(...)
renderer.draw(...)

renderer.endRendering()
glPopMatrix()
```

If I so much as switch the order of the last two lines, it stops working. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Call glRotatef before you beginRendering() the text.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)` just before calling glRotatef. You don't know what matrix mode the beginRendering method leaves OpenGL in.